# How to summarize count() by bin of 1 day and add default value for the missing days in the timeframe in KQL

Tags: kql

I have this KQL:

```
traces
| where timestamp between (['_startTime'] .. ['_endTime'])
| where message == "Operation Success"
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1d)
```

Now the query is for 7 days, but there are timestamps only in 2 days out of the 7. I wish the other days will appear in the summarize but as zero's

E.g. current result:

| timestamp | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-25T00:00:00Z | 3 |
| 2023-04-27T00:00:00Z | 4 |

requested result:

| timestamp | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-23T00:00:00Z | 0 |
| 2023-04-24T00:00:00Z | 0 |
| 2023-04-25T00:00:00Z | 3 |
| 2023-04-26T00:00:00Z | 0 |
| 2023-04-27T00:00:00Z | 4 |
| 2023-04-28T00:00:00Z | 0 |
| 2023-04-29T00:00:00Z | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
traces
| where timestamp between (['_startTime'] .. ['_endTime'])
| where message == "Operation Success"
| make-series count() default = 0 on timestamp from _startTime to _endTime step 1d
| project-reorder timestamp, count_
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the *make-series* operator instead of *summarize*, e.g.

```
MyTable
| make-series count() on Timestamp from _startTime to _endTime step 1d
| mv-expand Timestamp, count_
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. But I wish to render timechart and keep getting this error (Could not figure out how to draw a timechart. Specifying x and y columns in render operator might help.) - even after specifying the x and y columns. Any idea if this should work with render timechart?

Comment: Simply drop the mv-expand line and place the render timechart after the make-series

Comment: Actually that didn't helped, I've had to add the | project-reorder timestamp, count_

Comment: What application version do you use? Try upgrading KE to the latest using https://aka.ms/ke and if still doesn't work - use "Report Issue" button.